# Indexing expression is invalid because subscript type 'float' is not an integral or Objective-C pointer type

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors

I've taken the task of converted a legacy 32-bit app to 64-bit. It's an open source application, and I've ran into the following issue.

> Indexing expression is invalid because subscript type 'float' is not an integral or Objective-C pointer type

It occurs on the line

```
- (FlxObject *) getRandom;
{
  return ((FlxObject *)(members[[FlxU floor:[FlxU random] * members.length]]));

}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried casting `[FlxU floor:[FlxU random]` to an `int`?

Comment: Honestly don't know how, I took this on as a hobby project, but I think I'm in too deep

Comment: Change `[FlxU floor:[FlxU random] * members.length]` to `(int)[FlxU floor:[FlxU random] * members.length]`. Function `floor:` probably returns a `float`, and indexes, for obvious reasons, need to be integers.

Comment: Hey that did it, nice work